# Why do so many Trekkies hate Star Trek Into Darkness?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness, star-trek-reboot, star-trek-movies

I am a fan of *Star Trek*. I've watched most episodes of all the series (especially *Star Trek: the Next Generation*, and not counting *Star Trek: Enterprise*), I've seen the movies, I can even tell you how Captain Picard likes his tea.

I watched *Star Trek Into Darkness*, and I liked it. It certainly has its flaws, but overall I quite enjoyed it.

However, there seem to be purists who consider it one of the worst *Star Trek* movies ever, maybe even worse than *Star Trek V: The Final Frontier*.

**What are some *Star Trek*-related reasons that a *Star Trek* fan would rank this film near the bottom of the list of *Star Trek* films?**

---

*This is not meant to imply that only a Trekkie could hate the movie nor that a Trekkie could only hate it for Trek-related reasons. I am just curious about the phenomenon of Trekkies hating it for Trek-related reasons.*

Comment: You're making a set of assumptions here, not all of them right. E.g. I'm NOT a purist (I'm probably not even a "real" Trekkie, having never watched DS9 or most of TOS). Yet I found ItD to be an bad film - not as "Star Trek" but as a film in general, so **the bad opinions don't necessarily get caused by "purism"**. Leaving that aside, your question is likely not answerable in the Stack Exchange format, as it is likely to solicit opinion more than verifiable answers.

Comment: @Woody - I'm gonna have to see actual survey that proves the bad opinions are "mainly" purists before conceding your assertion. My personal anecdotal experience (not just me but most of my peer cohort) is the opposite.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile In any case there is a phenomenon of purists hating it, and that's what I'm asking about. I'm sure there are non-purists who hate it as well, just as there are a number of people who hate every movie

Comment: @Woody — I don't understand how any of DVK's statements could be interpreted to suggest that it is "objectively a bad movie". As for "there is a notion out there" … there are lots of notions out there, but that doesn't mean they are majority opinions, even within a specific group. I would expect "True X fans should hate X 2" to be quite a common opinion among X fans who hated X 2 for any given value of X.

Comment: @Quentin - not sure how it came off, but I most certainly tried to express that "bad" was my personal subjective opinion (but shared by others).

Comment: @Woody You can flag them for mods, but in this case there isn't much point since I'm already here :-) I've now **[copied all the comments to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44603/discussion-on-question-by-woody-why-do-trekkies-hate-into-darkness)** and will delete some of the less constructive ones from here.

Comment: They also have new generation cellphones in ItD :-) i know it supposedly sends data thru 'sub-space' so no delay, but it's still funny. Maybe cos we're total no0bs in Star Trek and watched it for the first time last week. We cried tears of mirth.

Comment: This is one of the most opinion-based questions I've ever seen stay open.

Comment: @DCShannon see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108486/what-was-the-general-critical-reaction-to-star-trek-the-motion-picture  - I'm basically asking the same thing

Comment: Because it's a terrible film... Is that my subjective opinion? Well, of course it is. Why does anyone like or dislike _any_ film? How is this question answerable, I wonder.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you are correct, saying 'because it's a terrible film' is not a valid answer. A valid answer would be one that includes specific aspects of the movie that are problematic in a Star Trek sense - either going against fundamental Star Trek principles, or contradicting canon in some way, etc.

Comment: @Woody: But "because it's a terrible film" is a huge reason of why people dislike it. Assuming that all Trek fans who hate the film only do so because it violates one or more of their sacred rules, and that such fans do not have sufficient intellectual capacity to form an actual opinion of their own that goes beyond a religious mantra, is pretty offensive to all those fans (myself included).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, I never made any such assumption, and if you think I did I'm sorry that you feel offended. I never said ALL Trek fans ONLY hate it for that reason, just that there are those who do, so I'm asking for the details of THOSE grievances. I am well aware that there are some out there who think it was just 'a terrible film'.

Comment: @Woody: I should have said "_would be_ offensive" :)

Comment: Why is this closed as "opinion based"? The querant is **not** asking for *our* opinion, but rather for (as the answer shows) well documented responses by the audience.

Comment: @SQB:  The audience is us?

Comment: But the question is not, "did you like the film or not and why?"; the question is, "why was the film received badly by the hard core fans?" which is _not_ opinion based. It may receive opinion based _answers_, but the question itself does not solicit them.

Answer (score 60):

## *Into Darkness* contradicts prior Star Trek canon in disturbing ways and at the same time ends up lampooning elements of *Wrath of Khan*, a beloved Star Trek film.

I'm a Star Trek "purist", but also a film fan in general, and I believe the fundamental problem with *Into Darkness* is that it **makes no sense**. (Case in point: Why would Khan hide his friends in torpedoes?  Why would he run off leaving them in weapons that will eventually be inspected...or even used?!)

But you asked for **Star Trek-related reasons**, and so I will give them to you.

## Transporter range

"Transporter range" is a fluid concept in Star Trek, being whatever it needs to be for a particular episode.  **But it has never been quadrant-sized** (unless you are the Iconians, but that's another story....)  *Into Darkness* presents the idea that you can now just transport from Earth to Qo'noS (the Klingon homeworld, near the Alpha and Beta Quadrant border).  They try to justify it with Scotty's transwarp beaming equations, but why did the same idea not develop in the prime timeline between Scotty's time and, say, the *Next Generation* era?

## Magic blood

McCoy is a smart man in any timeline.  Why would he not realize in the prime timeline that Khan's blood can bring the dead back to life?  (Or maybe the question is: why would McCoy in the reboot timeline be injecting dead Tribbles with Khan's blood for fun?  What's up with that?) The answer for why we never saw this before is that the idea is silly.  **In *Into Darkness*, death is irrelevant now.**  Many fans found this upsetting.

## Khan...

Great lengths were taken to **trick the audience** before this film came out.  Orci, Kurtzman, Abrams, and Lindelof had settled on the idea that they would parallel / remake *Wrath of Khan* to some extent, but didn't want the viewership to know about this until they were in the cinema on opening night.

To do this, they constructed the character of "John Harrison", played by Benedict Cumberbatch who looks nothing like Khan in the prime timeline (played by Ricardo Montalban).  Cumberbatch and others attached to *Into Darkness* gave responses that were technically true but not spiritually true during interviews, in order maintain the ruse.  For example:

> "I play a character called John and not that other name," Benedict continued. "It’s interesting. Speculation is speculation and that’s all fun."

([Source](https://www.accesshollywood.com/articles/benedict-cumberbatch-im-not-playing-khan-in-star-trek-into-darkness-126969/))

But despite all of the statements to the contrary, Cumberbatch's character was indeed Khan.  Recall that Khan was born in the 20th Century, before the timelines diverged, and so there is no reason for drastic changes of appearance. Some things are always in the eye of the beholder, **but they really look nothing alike.**  Putting Cumberbatch's popularity and acting credentials aside, it's not crazy to think he was cast at least in part to throw off fans and ensure the surprise of the eventual Khan reveal.  That's not a good motivation to cast someone.

[image]

Furthermore, the Khan character in *Into Darkness* has confusing motivations, from the point of view of long-term Star Trek fans.  This new Khan was overly emotionally concerned with his "family" (other genetic augments) and cried over his inability to protect them.  It's hard to assess this point without veering into opinion, but this doesn't seem to be a sound interpretation of Khan as we knew him in "Space Seed" and *Wrath*.  This was a man who ruled a quarter of the world with an iron fist.  The Khan of the prime timeline, while displaying respect for his fellow augments and measured affection towards his lover Marla McGivers, was never shown to be moved to tears over their plight, even at the height of their despair on Ceti Alpha V as he recounted the deaths of many of them in addition to that of his wife. In that same scene in *Wrath*, he reaffirmed how the other augments were to **"live and die by my command"**.  This new Khan, who is supposed to be the same man who fought through the same Eugenics Wars and experienced the same exile from Earth, seemed as if he might not sacrifice a single one of them for any reason.

[image]

Overall, the mid-movie Khan-reveal gambit did not pay off and fans were left debating whether or not the portrayal was accurate instead of focusing on the plot.

## The Kirk death scene

Finally, Kirk's death scene came off as a parody of Spock's in *Wrath of Khan*, especially with the Khan scream.  It simply didn't work, nor was there any in-universe reason for them to repeat exact lines from *Wrath* at a different time and under different circumstances.

## Some Further Reading

- [*Star Trek Into Darkness* Hostile to Star Trek, Intelligence](http://sequart.org/magazine/21469/star-trek-into-darkness-hostile-to-star-trek-intelligence/)
- [*Into Darkness* Had Too Many *Wrath of Khan* Nods](http://screenrant.com/star-trek-darkness-wrath-khan-references-abrams/)
- [14 Things That Made *Into Darkness* So Controversial](http://www.blastr.com/2013-9-11/14-things-made-star-trek-darkness-so-controversial)
- [*Into Darkness* Disappointed Even J.J. Abrams](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/117547/20151218/star-trek-into-darkness-even-disappointed-j-j-abrams.htm)

Comment: Very nice and detailed. These are  of course some of the major problems fans had. In the  interest of objectivity,  though, maybe it would be helpful to add some references (articles etc.)  indicating that these opinions are widespread,  and not just those of one purist.

Comment: @Adamant : Done.  (I resisted citing articles at first precisely because I didn't want it to seem that I was toeing the "party line" and just repeating other Trekkies' complaints.  So for posterity, let me just say that my write-up above was fully composed *before* I added in any references.)

Comment: One point maybe also: How the heck did a constitution class ship manage to get to Kronos without a single klingon space ship trying to hail it or stop it?! (never could wrap my head around that one.....and then a second even bigger ship appears in the same system without any klingon defense ships showing up).....pacifist demilitarizied klingons?

Comment: @Thomas : Starships also seem to be able to warp from Qo'noS to Earth in a few minutes, as the Vengeance chase scene seems to suggest.

Comment: @Adamant: "maybe it would be helpful to add some references (articles etc.) indicating that these opinions are widespread" - please do note that one of the issues that fans have with *Into Darkness* (and also some other parts of the Abramsverse) is that you do not have to venture deeply into opinion territory, but you can simply stick with the facts as shown on screen to stumble over plot problems.

Comment: @praxis that I could live with, but a defenseless kronos.......just makes absolutely no sense at all. (why again were the klingons.....a danger?)

Comment: @Thomas : Agreed.  The film just has too many things that make no sense.

Comment: I really liked this movie, but I only saw it the one time in the theater. Now I'm worried about rewatching it.

Comment: Consider also that in TWOK, Kirk and Spock have had a bro-mance spanning multiple decades prior to the engine room scene; in Into Darkness, they're barely over the mutual animosity featured in reboot#1 and there goes Spock shedding tears? Prior to the reboot, starships could barely handle flight in an atmosphere, let alone land or double as a submarine.

Comment: Hollywood is business. The Abrams movies were engineered by the studio to fill seats in order to maximize return on a big-budget investment. That means broad appeal, not catering to a niche fan base. So they took everything iconic about the original series and jammed it into a formula comedy/action/adventure movie - the kind which always costs a lot but sells really well. Canon be damned, you've got all the recognizable characters saying and doing their trademark things, a cool Enterprisey-looking spaceship, and lots of ray gun and explosion action; what more could anyone want?

Comment: The "further reading" references are excellent sources of insight. Just beware: the first one ("Intelligence"), although comprehensive, is somewhat rambling and repetitive.

Comment: Just remembered some reasons are touched on in the honest trailer videos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTfBH-XFdSc https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6B22Uy7SBe4

Comment: I have seen most of the trek movies but wrath of khan wasn't one of them. So for me, except for the name nothing was familiar. I liked the movie. On that note, (replying to one of the previous comments)I think the one reason why the spaceships were more adaptable than older ones were because today we have better technology & some things feel natural which previously were thought as far fetched or pointless. Its a new idea which is a possibility in the near future due to advance in technology and man-made compounds.(corrosion free?buoyant?) one can question the plot line but not the technology.

Comment: "Transporter range" is a fluid concept in Star Trek, being whatever it needs to be for a particular episode. But it has never been quadrant-sized" In DS9, the Dominion had transporter technology that worked over at least a few lightyears. Although, it was not Scotty who invented it, but likely a Changeling. By the end of DS9, the Federation certainly had this technology. I agree though, in fact, I think this was the worst Star Trek movie ever, even worse than Nemesis.

Comment: I'm someone who has actually seen the remake before the original (not because of age, just never got around to it before), and I gotta say, I don't think the original holds up today. I mean fans might think it's sacrilege to mess with it - but (IMO, obviously), by the standards of today's movies, the original is kinda campy, with so-so acting (and yes, I very much include the original "KHAAAN!!!" - I mean, look at it!), and the whole movie feels a little rinky dink when compared with the remake. I think that, if you want the Star Trek character of Khan to survive, the original is just too old.

Comment: I still consider [this commentary](https://io9.gizmodo.com/star-trek-into-darkness-the-spoiler-faq-508927844) to be definitive on the subject. It's like Snarky Luke Skywalker from *The Last Jedi* reviewed the movie.

Comment: Do you have any evidence the death scene was meant to "lampoon" *WoK*? I took it as a poorly handled attempt to replicate a classic moment in Trek Lore.

Comment: @RogueJedi : I wrote "ends up lampooning" not "meant to lampoon".  Only the latter implies intent.

Answer (score 3):

JJ Abrams himself has expressed regrets about how *Into Darkness* played out. In [this Buzzfeed interview](https://www.buzzfeed.com/kateaurthur/jj-abrams-and-the-long-road-to-star-wars%23.pyR358Xp27)

> But by the time we started shooting, and this was literally at the very beginning of the shoot, there were certain things I was unsure of.

And I found this comment to be quite astute (emphasis mine)

> "**I felt like, in a weird way, it was a little bit of a collection of scenes that were written by my friends** — brilliantly talented writers — who I somehow misled in trying to do certain things. And yet, I found myself frustrated by my choices, and unable to hang my hat on an undeniable thread of the main story,” Abrams said. “So then I found myself on that movie basically tap-dancing as well as I could to try and make the sequences as entertaining as possible. Thank god I had the cast that we have, who are so unbelievably fun to watch. And an incredible new villain in Benedict Cumberbatch."

Comment: *Yeah, it was bad, but, you see, it's not my fault, but my friends'...*

Comment: ... My writer friends ate my homework....