# Are there any people of Indian descent in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek

My question is simple.  **Have there ever been any characters, or actors of Indian descent in any of the Star Trek official canon, and if not is there some in universe explanation/theory as to why they are so vastly under represented?**

The caveat here is that yes I am aware that Khan Noonien Singh has an Indian last name.  I cannot recall though if in TOS or the original Wrath of Khan if they explicitly communicated if he is in fact of Indian descent.  For that matter if he was of Indian descent, why in multiple appearances of this character did they not use the opportunity to cast an Indian actor to play Khan?

Are there any in universe or out of universe explanations for the lack of representation here?  In a prior nuclear war did Pakistan and India blow each other off the map?

Comment: Khan is identified as being (probably) ethnically Indian in Space Seed.

Comment: @NKCampbell There was an East Asian (Chinese? Japanese?) engineer in the TNG Season 1 episode "The Naked Now". There was another TNG episode where an engineer of Indian descent was electrocuted, but I can't remember which season or episode.

Comment: @maple_shaft It's true that Ricardo Montalban was not Indian, but I do think the character was intended to be Indian, as is supported by source material (see Valorum's answer below).  Regarding Khan in subsequent appearances --- namely, *Into Darkness* --- the casting choice there seems to be inspired at least in part by [frivolous reasons](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139020/why-do-trekkies-hate-into-darkness/139050#139050).

Comment: @Praxis good point about Khan. There are plenty of other cases where an actor plays a character of a different ethnicity to the actor. James Doohan, an Irish-Canadian with a knack for accents, played Montgomery Scott on TOS and played him up as the stereotypical Scotsman.

Comment: Let’s not forget Commander Chakotay from Voyager. He was highly ranked.

Comment: @tchrist Wrong kind of Indian.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Let's not forget that Sir Patrick Stewart is not actually French.

Comment: _why in multiple appearances of this character did they not use the opportunity to cast an Indian actor to play Khan?_ In universe explanation: it's a different universe, so details (like a character's ethnicity in this case) can differ. Out of universe explanation: Hollywood has a race problem.

Comment: *"why in multiple appearances of this character did they not use the opportunity to cast an Indian actor to play Khan"* "Two" is typically not described as "multiple." With Ricardo Montalbán they at least had him *look* slightly Indian. With Benedict Cumberbatch, well, I think they were just jumping on the Benedict Cumberbatch revenue train.

Comment: The new khan's ethnic makeup is not even mentioned, just that he's the product of a genetic experiment that was deemed a failure, since every one of the super soldiers produced were, unsurprisingly with their enhanced intelligence, sociopathic.  In the modern, PC-before-all country of the USA, attaching any ethnic description to such a character would be seen as defamatory toward that ethnicity, deserved or not.  What I loved about ST was that it envisioned a world where people literally do not discriminate (original meaning - to mark a difference between two things) along those sort of lines.

Comment: @Xalorous ..."were, unsurprisingly with their enhanced intelligence, sociopathic"... Smart people are sociopaths?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder -- three appearances, two actors.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: Yes. And sticking with Montalbán for the second appearance was absolutely the right choice.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder And the 80s hair metal band hair was also a good choice?

Comment: @maple_shaft: Hey, it was 1982. Do you *really* want to get into a discussion of poor hair choices in the ST universe? Particularly TOS and related films? ;-)

Comment: @Shane A surprising number of genius level intellects are sociopaths, yes.  They operate by their own standards of ethics and right and wrong.  They do not do tings because the world around them says those things are right, but instead because they have considered the options and reasoned the right course, by their own standards.  Those standards are usually developed after discarding societal standards because those are often based on superstition or traditions which are themselves based on forgotten standards.  You are probably confusing sociopathic as I used it with criminally sociopathic.

Comment: *why in multiple appearances of this character did they not use the opportunity to cast an Indian actor to play Khan?* - Because Rodenberry was always promoting a better world, a better human race.  Where people are not judged based on irrelevant bases, like the color of skin.  Because Abrams honored Rodenberry enough to continue this by removing ethnic references from the Khan story.

Comment: @Xalorous Too bad minorities among real life actors didn't get the memo about us living in a post-ethnic world. Or have I missed a black Captain Kirk? Or an Asian Spock?

Comment: @MishaRosnach Obviously it's the Star Trek world that is a better world.  Spock is a freaking Vulcan which is a completely different species, so why would they have a Terran racial background.  Multiple black actors have played Terran commanders/captains in ST, including my favorite ST captain ever, Avery Brooks as Commander Sisko in DS9, and one of the best actors working today, Idris Elba in the most recent movie.  Captain Sulu is another example of a Terran non-white character.  The main character in Discovery is a black female whose captain in the beginning is an Asian female.

Comment: @MishaRosnach When did this question get diverted from examples characters of Indian descent in ST lore to anti-whitewashing.  You and I are not going agree, because you obviously believe in converting stories after the fact to promote forced diversity.  While I believe in changing the world to remove bias.

Comment: @Xalorous Your argument would work in a perfect world. But in a world where casting a non-white actor to play Khan is "forced diversity" and casting a white one is "honoring Rodenberry," it's a non-argument.

Comment: @MishaRosnach ST:TOS was groundbreaking in that it was extremely socially progressive.  It stimulated awareness and discussion of social issues of the time.  Including diversity.  Look at the cast.  Incredibly diverse for that day and age.  TNG and DS9 continued this,  and the new series.  Enterprise and the reboots?  To me they're less diverse, racially, more on other topics.  Do I think Khan was badly done?  No.  I like Benedict Cumberbatch and I think he did a fine job.  Do I agree that choosing a Caucasian actor was poor casting due to the current socio-political environment? Yes.

Answer (score 70):

[**Captain Chandra**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Chandra_(Captain)) from *TOS* episode "Courtmartial."

[image: Headshot of Captain Chandra]

Played by Reginald Lal Singh

Comment: This is a good one --- very early in Star Trek.

Comment: Is there any confirmation that he's Indian? Other than having an Indian-sounding name and looking Indian, obviously.

Comment: ...and the actor's *actual* name of course...but he was born in 1905 in British Guiana...but his ancestry...I dunno.

Answer (score 60):

In *Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home*, there is a ship commanded by an Indian captain, the U.S.S. *Yorktown*. His name is [Captain Joel Randolph](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Joel_Randolph). His ship has been disabled when it encountered the alien probe. He talks about the solar sail they are crafting and the high hopes they have for it.

By accent alone I'd say he's of Indian decent for sure. He was played by [Vijay Amritraj](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vijay_Amritraj).

[image: Headshot of Captain Randolph, against a backdrop of bridge consoles obscured by smoke]

Comment: Well, the [actor](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Vijay_Amritraj) who portrayed him is Indian.

Comment: Extremely common Indian surname, is "Randolph".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit so surname determines ethnicity?

Comment: @congusbongus No, but neither does the ethnicity of the actor determine the ethnicity of the character.

Comment: @congusbongus: Well, _yes_. Ethnicity and culture are strongly linked; culture and family names almost go hand in hand. Know many Caucasians called "Singh", do you? Of course there are exceptions, particularly as global social mobility increases, though less so down male lines as long as current traditions are maintained. If you take a census of all male people currently alive with this character's ethnicity, I'd put decent money on _none_ of them having the surname "Randolph". Not sure how this can be argued against; feel free to give it a go if you'd like to present some counter-arguments :)

Comment: @congusbongus: If you're suggesting that the character could still be Indian despite the surname, please read again and observe that I was not claiming otherwise. Merely pointing out an interesting and related fact. This is the comments section, after all!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - quite a few Indian families have adopted western (mostly English and Portuguese) surnames (particularly when converting to Christianity) - one of my university lecturers' surnames was Johnson, and another was Thompson - they had migrated to Britain from India several decades earlier as children, and still had a discernible accent. So, it is not impossible for a "Randolph" to be of Indian descent.

Comment: @HorusKol: Interesting. I know a huge number of British families of Indian descent and this is news to me. Again, though, I don't dispute it's possible; just that (at the very least) it's unusual... which is all I ever said :)

Comment: @Kik: Yep - the adoption scenario is the most plausible to me. Good thinking!

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Concerning "Know many Caucasians called "Singh"", see [Are Indians considered Caucasian or Asian?](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120201203236AANYSXs)

Comment: @chux: Okay well you know what I mean

Answer (score 52):

In the *TNG* episode "[The Lonely Among Us](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lonely_Among_Us_(episode))", [Lieutenant Junior Grade Singh](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Singh_(Lieutenant_jg)) was the assistant chief engineer of the *Enterprise* under Chief Engineer Argyle. **He didn't last long.**

> *Lieutenant Singh was played by [Kavi Raz](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kavi_Raz) and was the first crew member of the Enterprise-D killed on Star Trek: The Next Generation.*

[image: Lt. (JG) Singh sits in a chair on the bridge, back to the viewscreen and the starfield effect.]

(thanks to NKCampbell for the reminder)

Comment: This was the other Indian I was struggling to remember. He was killed in the TNG: 1x07 episode "Lonely Among Us".

Comment: Hmm... Not wearing red shirt.

Comment: at the risk of a 'me too' comment @RobertF ...I'll say nothing other than to reference my own comment to OP :)

Comment: To be fair, the Enterprise D went through **4** *chief* engineers *before*  La Forge...

Comment: @RobertHarvey they swapped red and gold between TOS and TNG...

Answer (score 48):

Lt. Rahda, the replacement helm officer in the episode "That Which Survives", is shown wearing a bindi (a traditional Hindu symbol) on her forehead.

[image: Lt. Rahda at the helm station with the targeting scanner in front of her]

Comment: Kinda looks like Alice from the Brady Bunch.

Comment: @LarsTech: It's the hair.

Comment: Played by Naomi Pollack, born on May 17, 1930 in New York, New York, USA as Naomi D. Pollack.

Comment: She also has an Indian name. Radha is the consort of Krishna.

Answer (score 29):

Marla McGivers identifies [Khan Singh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khan_Noonien_Singh) as being (probably) of Indian descent.

> **MARLA:** *Yes, sir. The leader was often set to revive first. This would allow him to decide whether the conditions warranted revival of
> the others.*
>
> **MCCOY:** *Heart beat now approaching forty per minute. The respiration pattern is firming up.*
>
> **MARLA:** *From the northern India area, I'd guess. Probably a Sikh. They were the most fantastic warriors.*
>
> <sub><sup>[**TOS: Space Seed**](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/24.htm)</sup></sub>

This ties in nicely with the [prequel comic](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Khan) issued alongside the Star Trek Into Darkness film which identifies his place of birth as New Delhi, India.

[image: Panel from a cartoon showing a car zooming away from a ground-level viewpoint in a slum; in the foreground a rat watches the car. Text reads "New Delhi. November, 1971."]

This comic serial also deals with the reason why "John Harrison" looks so very different from his earlier portrayal in TOS. In short because his face was altered as part of an elaborate ruse to trick him into working for Section 31.

[image: The first panel is a head shot of a bald man, lying on his back, his face overlain with a laser alignment grid. It reads "The facial reconstruction was the easy part. Surgery's come a long way since the 20th century." The second panel has a person, with their head and face covered with a purple mask, looking at a comparison of two faces on side-by-side monitors. Specific parts of the faces are circled on the monitors. The skin of the face on the left is darker, and the brow and jaw are heavier. The face on the right is lighter-skinned, narrower and more angular with curved brows. It reads "We opted for a northern European look. Figured the further away we got from India the better. Vocal cord modulation was matched to your new identity as a researcher at Starfleet's London archive."]

Comment: Nice.  I believe the *Eugenics Wars* books by Greg Cox also identifies his birthplace as India.  Those books have at least semi-canon status (unlike most ST print media).  They are well received as filling in an important gap in Star Trek history and not contradicted by Alpha canon as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 17):

The reason that Indians, and all asians for that matter, are under represented to us is because in the Star Trek Universe during the Eugenics War and WWIII the Asian population was nearly completely wiped out. While you could say that 300 years is enough to recover I would point to the Native American population currently where there are very few pure blooded Native Americans remaining.

Then why are there more Native Americans than Asians? The answer to that is that Native Americans have largely been cloistered apart from other groups and so when Space Travel became a thing it wouldn't be out there to suspect that they'd leave and settle their own worlds apart from other human groups where as Asians, while xenophobic in a lot of ways have always blended and been a part of overall civilization meaning they likely would integrate, rather than separate and segregate on other worlds. This would lead to a regeneration of Native Americans while Asians would just become part of the common mix of humanity and their traits and pure lineages would slowly become more rare.

Comment: Is this speculation or is this well established in canon? I have heard this claim before but wasnt sure if this was ever explicitly stated.

Comment: It's established in canon loosely. The Eugenics War(s) were fought through out Asia, the Middle East, and North Africa. These are specifically mentioned and as such should be seen as the pre-dominant focus of events, but surely the Americas and Europe got involved in some way, but probably didn't suffer or fall to Eugenically engineered Rulers. Similarly the Post-Atomic Horrors and such were focused in Eastern European countries and Asia so we can assume this the combination resulted in massive populations dying on top of the recounted number of dead from WWIII.

Comment: Also if we assume a starting population of around 6billion. We know that more than 350 million asians died due to just the wars alone. That is more than 10% of their population. If we include the radiation, the genecides, post-atomic horror, and general fall into dark ages which comes with famines we can easily see that number rising several times over. Earth as a whole can only sustain 600mil HG style which they'd be living in leading which means their population probably fell by something like 90% taking it all into account.

Comment: If you want to add a reference, I believe the *Eugenics Wars* books by Greg Cox describe this. They are at least semi-canon (see my comment below Valorum's answer).

Comment: Is your assertion that "Asians [are] xenophobic in a lot of ways" an in-universe or a real-world observation?  If it's the latter, I find it a rather disturbing observation, and not the slightest bit rooted in truth.

Comment: @DavidWallace, any group that maintains a distinct cultural and racial identity while a minority group in a region should be considered to be as isolationist as, if not more than, the group they're failing to blend in with. You cannot maintain the identity through multiple generations without sticking to your own group.

Answer (score 13):

Wasn't Dr. Bashir Indian?

Also Captain Robau, George Kirk's captain in Star Trek (2009) was Pakistani or Indian, played by Faran Tahir (who interestingly is playing Othello on stage in DC these days).

[image: Bashir with parents]

[image: Captain Robau]
<sub>(source: [ex-astris-scientia.org](https://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/gallery/trekxi/robau-bridge.jpg))</sub>

Not to say they aren't under-represented... which I attribute to (a) blind spot on the writer's part or (b) targeting a local audience as opposed to an in-universe explanation such as eugenics wars which sounds more plausibly like a plot point to make up for said under-representation...

Comment: Bashir is either Arabic or North African.

Comment: "*In my mind, Julian was of Sudanese (like Sid), Indian, or Pakistani extraction, but that the family's roots were probably in England, hence the accents.*" - [Ronald D. Moore](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Memory_Alpha:AOL_chats/Ronald_D._Moore/ron049.txt)

Comment: "Sid" in the quote of Moore above would be a reference to Alexander Siddig (Siddig El Fadil), the actor who played Dr Bashir.

Comment: I'd agree that (subcontinent) Indians are under-represented, considering they are about a fifth of the world's population today. Probably the best explanation is that they wanted to depict a multicultural human society, but historically had to use the actors they had available to them half a century ago in LA.  That means they would naturally end up rather heavy on people of European descent, and same but to a lesser extent with people of African, Native North American, and east Asian descent.

Comment: ...the US Census didn't even count Indian Americans separately [until about 1980](http://www.pewsocialtrends.org/asianamericans-graphics/indians/), and at that point there were less than half a million of them in the entire country, with likely less than 100K of them in the western USA. That's as opposed to (in 1980) 3 times that many Native Americans, and 26 million "blacks".

Answer (score 4):

The character Lieutenant Ilia (*Star Trek the Motion Picture*) was a Deltan, and thus not any human ethnicity, but she was played by Persis Khambatta, an Indian actress, model, and author.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persis_Khambatta

Comment: Ilia was a non-human character, specifically a Deltan.

Comment: @Irishpanda thanks for the clarification. Would it be appropriate to edit that into the answer?