# Did readers find the metaphysical questions Donaldson raised compelling?

Tags: stephen-r-donaldson, thomas-covenant

This is, by its nature, a question about reader responses.  I am trying to get an understanding for how readers have reacted to certain elements in Stephen R. Donaldson's fantasy writing.  As such, there may not be a definitive correct answer.  Donaldson was hugely popular in the late 1970s and 1980s; in *[Realms of Fantasy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0905895835)*, a beautifully illustrated coffee table book about various fantasy worlds, he was described as having the greatest success of any of the various epic fantasy writers that had followed on Tolkien's heels.  [The book's analysis proved to be not particularly useful, as the time of its publication (1988) corresponded to the beginning of an explosion in the mediocre but heavily read fantasy book market.]

In a couple answers on this site, I have commented sarcastically on Donaldson's apparent fascinations with philosophical puzzles that his characters have to grapple with, in addition to their evil foes.  He points this out himself in the introduction to *Gilden Fire*, a novella that was originally intended to be part of the *The Illearth War* but was cut for pacing reasons and because it possibly conflicted with the main philosophical puzzle of the original *Chronicles of Thomas Covenant, the Unbeliever*:  whether The Land was real or a figment of Covenant's imagination.  In Donaldson's second series (*Mordant's Need*), the philosophical question is turned around; the puzzle is not whether the fantasy world is real, but whether the main character (and our universe, from whence she comes) was real or not.  (I have not read Donaldson's other major series, the *Gap* novels; seeing hundreds of remaindered hardcover copies of *Chaos and Order* at Buck a Book convinced me it probably wasn't worth my time.)

My question is this: **Did readers find the metaphysical questions Donaldson raised compelling?** Or were they generally seen as a distraction from the story? How much of a record is there of reader response to this aspect of Donaldson's work?

Comment: You've been on this site for more than long enough to know that this sort of question is off-topic. Per the [FAQ] ***"To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where … there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”***

Comment: @Valorum Doesn't a question about the fandom's response to particular aspects of a work of fantasy come under (per the FAQ) [fandom information](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - No. This is explicitly covered in the FAQ and on-topic question description. "***I feel like x, do other people agree?*** is not on-topic unless you can demonstrate at least some degree of notability. If you reworded the question as "*Did he ever speak about what reaction he wanted from fans*" (for example) then that would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Valorum Where does it say in the FAQ that one can't ask about how fans actually reacted (as opposed to how an author expected/wanted them to react)? Cf. [this very well-received question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/108486/31394) about reader - or in that case watcher - response to a specific work of sci-fi.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I can only point you at the FAQ. If you want to change it, I'd suggest you post a question on Meta - "*Should we allow questions where the OP wants to know what other fans think?"*

Comment: @Valorum You've mentioned the FAQ three times now, but I still can't see anywhere it says that asking about details of the fandom's reaction to a particular work is off-topic.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - What do you think "*I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”*" means?

Comment: @Valorum I think the personal angle is irrelevant to the real question here, and included only as motivation for why the OP asked it. Surely the essential question is "how did readers in general react to X?" Does it really matter that this happens to equate to "did other readers react to X in the same way I did"?

Comment: This is a chat question, sorry. It's only going to attract opinion-based commentary, especially since the question itself contains some.

Comment: Buzz - I've edited your question in an attempt to make it more reopenable, by focusing more clearly on the objectively answerable question here. I also removed much of your last paragraph, since that seemed to be asking something different ("does this make sense" as opposed to "what was reader response to this"). The good news is that the question only needs 2 more votes to get reopened, and you yourself can be one of them. (cc Valorum and @Adamant - would you agree that it's better now?)

Comment: @Randal'Thor asking for readers opinions isn't "Opinion based"?

Comment: @Edlothiad Asking for details of fandom response to a particular SF/F work? Nope, I wouldn't say that's POB, and we've had such questions before.

Comment: [Related meta post.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11785/31394)

Comment: Most good books include philosophical speculation in one form or another.  Books without it are like bubble gum - nice and chewy and tastes good, but only increases your hunger instead of filling your belly.